# How to load a Rails View inside an infobox using gmaps4rails & JQuery Ajax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, gmaps4rails

I would like to know how can I load a Rails View inside a Infobox opened by Gmaps4Rails.infobox.

Answer (score 1):

I did this way and work fine. O secret is put **serviceObject**, in some example show google_object.

```
<% content_for :scripts do %>
    <script>
        Gmaps4Rails.callback = function() {
            for (var i = 0; i <  this.markers.length; ++i) {
                google.maps.event.addListener(Gmaps4Rails.markers[i].serviceObject, 'click', function(){
                    $('#info').load('/messages');
                    $('#info').dialog("open");
                });

            }
        };
    </script>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Well done Luciano, I was just reading your question. I changed the name because I just added support for other map APIs so I needed to be generic.